# Pass parameter to Jenkins Ant job by HTTP POST

Tags: http, post, jenkins, ant

I try to start a Jenkins Ant job (not parameterized) by a URL and to pass a parameter to this job. To do this I use HTTP POST in Ant:

```
<taskdef name="http" classname="org.missinglink.ant.task.http.HttpClientTask"/>
<!-- using CDATA section to avoid having to escape the ampersand -->
<property name="jenkins.url"><![CDATA[${job.url}/build?myParameter=myValue&delay=0sec]]></property>
<http url="${jenkins.url}" method="POST">
    <credentials username="myUsername" password="myPassword"/>
</http>
```

The job starts without a problem, but in the job's Ant script `myParameter` is undefined.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: A URL can have, at most, one question mark (`?`) to separate the hierarchical part from the query. Attribute–value pairs are then separated by ampersands (`&`). So, a valid URL should be: `${job.url}/build?myParameter=myValue&delay=0sec`

Comment: Thx, you're right! But, using the correct URL, unfortunatelly myParameter's value still isn't passed to the Ant script.

Comment: I've added the `jenkins` tag to the question because an answer appears to require knowledge about Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the jenkins url:

```
${job.url}/buildWithParameters?myParameter=myValue&delay=0sec
```